# How to change jar output directory in Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, jar

I was wondering if it is possible to change jar output file into other directory like on desktop or somewhere else? If so, how do I do that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

For Gradle 5.1+:

```kotlin
jar {
    destinationDirectory.set(file("$buildDir/someDir"))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try with the following changes.

```
jar{
   destinationDir = file("$rootDir/someDir")
}
```

Comment: That's a deprecated way to do that. Isn't there a better or modern way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I use this syntax for Kotlin DSL (`build.gradle.kts`)

```
tasks.withType<Jar> {
    destinationDirectory = File("$rootDir/someDir")
}
```